# How to read XML Data using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have below XML format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Partners Default="123">
<PID id="123" Value="Kell Partners" DefGID="345">
          <GID id="345" Country="US" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month" Default="True"></GID>
          <GID id="455" Country="US" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month"></GID>
          <GID id="789" Country="US" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month"></GID>
          <GID id="159" Country="EU" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month" Default="True"></GID>
</PID>
<PID id="456" Value="Test Company 2" DefGID="224">
          <GID id="222" Country="CA" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month" Default="True"></GID>
          <GID id="224" Country="CA" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month"></GID>
          <GID id="225" Country="UK" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month"></GID>
          <GID id="226" Country="UK" Value="3.5% + $0.35/transaction + $0/month" Default="True"></GID>
</PID>
</Partners>
```

I am using below code snippet to read xml data in PHP where My xml showing parents nodes as @attributes.

```
<?php
$xmlparser=simplexml_load_file("partners.xml") or die("Cannot open the file.");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xmlparser->attributes());

?>
```

In above question I want read the

default from Partners node..I am unable to read by using above code..

and by using Default i will get the child nodes data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("partners.xml") or die("Cannot open the file.");
echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    foreach($child as $value) {
        print_r($value->children());
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

By this code you can get the data of `GID` nodes. To get it you don't have to get Partners Default value.

Comment: this only getting child nodes....I want to get <Partners Default="123"> default value from this node, based on parent node I will get child node.

Comment: `$xml` is root here. `$xml->children()` will get child `PID` nodes, `$xml->attributes()['Default']` will get you `Default` value `123`